# Array trees finding parents and ther parents and the shortes path to the root

Tags: java, arrays, path, tree, nodes

I want to find the shortest route from a child, to his parent, to grandparent and in the end the root.

For example, `input 0 0 0 1 2`, means that:

```
input[1] parent is 0 (route = 1)
input[2] also has parent 0 (route = 1) 
input[3] has parent 1 which has parent 0 (route = 2)
input[4] has parent 2 which has parent 0 (route = 2)
```

Code so far:

Array is created called `targetNodes` which contains `0 0 0 1 2`,

```
System.out.print( "0 " );

for ( int x = 1; x < arrayLength; x++ )
{

  int depth = 1;
  int parent = 0;

  while ( targetNodes[x] != 0 ) 
  {
      depth++;
      targetNodes[x] = targetNodes[ targetNodes[x] ] ;
  }   

  // output shortest path from node to root for every node
  System.out.print( depth + " " );

}

System.out.print("\n");
```

My example works and with input: `0 0 0 1 2` it prints: `0 1 1 2 2`, 
but for input: `0 0 1 2 1 4` it prints out: `0 1 2 2 2 2` when the correct output would be: `0 1 2 3 2 3`

Not sure what I am doing wrong, I would guess it's the logic

Comment: It's not really clear to me what your code does, but you should definitely separate the logic from the output. Create a method `int[] findPathLengths(int[] nodeDefinitions)`. Then you can easily write unit tests for this method.

Comment: I'm assuming that `targetNodes` contains the relationships between the nodes. Since finding the shortest distance does not modify these relationships in any way, so shouldn't your code. Don't assign to `targetNodes[x]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually pretty simple. The hardest part was to convert the data for the unit tests, so that they can be efficiently typed.

```
package so7455242;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;

import com.google.common.primitives.Ints;

public class DistanceFinder {

  private static int[] findPathLengths(int[] parent) {
    int[] distances = new int[parent.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < parent.length; i++) {
      int distance = 0;
      for (int node = i; node != 0; node = parent[node]) {
        distance++;
      }
      distances[i] = distance;
    }
    return distances;
  }

  private static int[] toIntArray(String s) {
    String[] words = s.split(" ");
    int[] ints = new int[words.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < ints.length; i++) {
      ints[i] = Integer.parseInt(words[i]);
    }
    return ints;
  }

  private static void testcase(String expected, String input) {
    int[] nodeDefinitions = toIntArray(input);
    int[] pathLengths = findPathLengths(nodeDefinitions);
    String actual = Ints.join(" ", pathLengths);
    assertEquals(expected, actual);
  }

  @Test
  public void test() {
    testcase("0 1 1 2 2", "0 0 0 1 2");
    testcase("0 1 2 3 2 3", "0 0 1 2 1 4");
  }

}
```